# How do I tell Prolog that a specific tuple is not in a list

Tags: prolog

So I tried to tell prolog that in Lst there's a tuple with (a,b,*) but the last tuple member is not 2 but there are other elements in Lst that might contain (*,_,2).

```
test(A,B,C) :-
    length(Lst, 2),
    member((A,B,C), Lst),

    member((c,d,_), Lst),
    member((a,b,F), Lst),
    F \= 2,
    member((_,_,2), Lst),
    member((_,_,3), Lst).
```

When I queried for test(c,d,2) it returned false.

```
test(A,B,C) :-
    length(Lst, 2),
    member((A,B,C), Lst),

    member((c,d,_), Lst),
    member((a,b,F), Lst),
    F \= 2,
    member((_,_,2), Lst),
```

Comment: Prolog doesn't have tuples that look like this. In Prolog, tuples do not look like this: `(a, b, c)`. Those are not Prolog tuples. This: `(c,d,_)` is not a tuple in Prolog.

Comment: See here: https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/prolog-convention-of-pairs-and-tuples/5385 and also here: https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/surprising-result-with-equals-dot-dot/4989/18

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From [the SWI Prolog documentation on \=](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=%5c%3d%2f2) availble by querying `?- help(\=).` :

> This predicate is logically sound if its arguments are sufficiently instantiated

Your `F` isn't instantiated (it isn't bound to any value, so you can't tell that it's *not* some specific value).

> To make your programs work correctly also in situations where the arguments are not yet sufficiently instantiated, use dif/2 instead.

Change `F \= 2` to `dif(F, 2)`